# Convert a date value in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a value as `2013-01-18` in this format as date datatype, I need to convert this as `Fri, Jan 18, 2013` in SQL Server 2008.

How do I convert ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = '2013-01-18'
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @dt), 3) + ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @dt, 107)
```

However, be careful, `CONVERT` function with 107 parameter isn't deterministic, it depends on local language settigs, you can read more about it at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Same goes for `DATENAME` function, read more about it at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), SYSDATETIME(), 107) AS [Mon DD, YYYY]
```

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eca79/1

```
CREATE TABLE person 
    (
     id int identity primary key, 
     created date
    );

INSERT INTO person
(created)
VALUES
('12/1/2003'),
('1/3/2014');

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(DAY, created)) + ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, created, 107) AS Complete
FROM person
```